# How to remove the last "-" in a text string when a number follows it

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have multiple text columns with IDs. I want to remove the "-" only if it is the last one and the following character is a number. Please show tidyverse syntax as I will be mutating across multiple columns.

EX

```
data <- data.frame(id = c("2022-05-19-admin-raca-16", "2022-05-19-admin-hyla16"))
```

Desired Outputs

```
correct_data <- data.frame(id = c("2022-05-19-admin-raca16", "2022-05-19-admin-hyla16"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_remove` with a 'look ahead' part to detect following numbers:

- "-" is the part you want to remove
- "(?=\\d+$)" means 'followed by one or more digits at the end of the string' (but leave these there).

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  data.frame(id = c("2022-05-19-admin-raca-16", "2022-05-19-admin-hyla16"))

data |>
  mutate(id = str_remove(id, "-(?=\\d+$)"))
#>                        id
#> 1 2022-05-19-admin-raca16
#> 2 2022-05-19-admin-hyla16
```